# how can golang find libc library file in windows during cross compilation

Tags: go, cross-compiling

just a very simple code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, you've requested: %s\n", r.URL.Path)
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8011", nil)
}
```

if this code is built on linux with CGO_ENABLE=1, it will depends on libc.so

but when i build on windows like

```
SET CGO_ENABLED=0
SET GOOS=linux
SET GOARCH=amd64
go build -o my_http my_http.go
```

i think the libc library is built statically, but where is linux libc library in GOROOT, i check the folder

```
bin
lib
pkg
```

only have some a suffix files

maybe i didn't understand the cross-compilation in go, so any related articles is welcomed

Comment: if 'SET CGO_ENABLED=0' it will use `pkg\windows_amd64\net\http.a` but libc

Comment: http.a file contains all the linux,windows,osx syscall with network functionality implementation, right?